# Can I use corrugated metal roofing panels as soffits and paint them?

Tags: paint, roofing, soffit

I have several sheets of Corrugated Steel Roofing (see picture) from a replaced roof, and I would like to re-use them as a soffit under a porch, and paint them white or black.

**How should I prep the sheets, and what type of paint should I use?**

The soffits are obviously outside but not directly exposed to rain/snow or sun/UV: they are mounted with the "exterior" side down, not up as would be the case with a roof.

The panels/sheets are from a used roof and after some scrubbing/power washing they seem to be in good condition.

My thoughts were:

- power wash & scrub moss etc...
- light sanding to scruff the surface
- maybe muratic acid, maybe primer?
- paint with exterior acrylic, but maybe interior latex would work too?
- to apply paint, use a roller? or brush?

No rain/snow, no sun/UV, but wet climate.

[image]

Comment: I would pay special attention to rust removal, priming, and painting of the existing screw holes. Even though this is weather protected, I would also reuse existing screw holes whenever possible to minimize additional punctures through the rust protection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I prep the sheets, and what type of paint should I use?

- power wash & scrub moss etc. **YES**
- light sanding to scruff the surface **YES**
- maybe muratic acid, maybe primer? **NO** to both. Neither is necessary assuming those panels already have paint on them, which looks to be true. If your "light" sanding creates any bare metal areas, spot prime those.
- paint with exterior acrylic **YES**
- ...maybe interior latex would work too? **NO** why would you use *interior* paint for an exterior application?
- use a roller? or brush? **YES** either/both, or spray

Comment: I have read that oil based paints are better for adhesion, And longevity, to metal surfaces, no ?

Comment: Clear and complete! Yes I was concerned with creating bare areas that would be ungalvanized, so I am glad you mention that. For primer: a rust primer? As for interior latex, only because of the price: there are some cheaper brands with which I have had great interior results.

Comment: A special rust primer would not be critical but if that's what I had then I would use it. A bonding primer or oil-based grey metal primer would be great too. I would not use something like interior drywall primer. If I had a high-quality *interior* gloss or semi-gloss acrylic paint on hand... I would probably go for it rather than spend more $$. @Alaska Man, water-based paints have come a long way baby and in a protected location such as described will last for decades. No problem adhering to a properly prepared, previously painted surface. I would use exterior acrylic with a sheen.

Comment: Just some feedback: this generally worked well, except on some spots the latex did not attach. When I marked a drill hole with a sharpie it peeled off. I had scrubbed and cleaned with baking soda (and rinsed), dried in sun, so I am not sure what the cause was. Maybe I missed a spot. Not a biggie, 2nd coat goes on after installation. Still I'd like to learn, if you have any thoughts on this. Thanks anyway!